# Why Jmeter thread group configration are different in Blaze meter?

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am trying to do performance test of my Rest API via **Jmeter** and generating report from [blaze Meter](https://sense.blazemeter.com).

I am testing a POST operation. I want to send 50 request to the server by 50 users, means that each 1 user gonna send 1 request with delay of 1 second. I want to send 1 request by 1 user so it will make 50 request by 50 users.
My Jmeter Configrations are: 
No of Threads: 50
Ramp up peroid : 50
Loop Count: 1

But When I genrate report via **Blaze Meter**, my  **Max Virtual Users** are 4
instead of 50. Why is it 4? What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Max Virtual Users` means max concurrent users.

Having 50 thread and a ramp up of 50 seconds in a single loop cycle, not all threads are concurrently running; when some threads already finished other have still to start.

You should get a greater `Max Virtual Users` value running multiple loop cycles.

Comment: oh I see. Thank you ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Just increase loop count, you are running into a situation when some threads have already finished their job and others have not yet been started.

See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article for detailed explanation.